# Progressive JPEG using RMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to convert a JPEG image into progressive JPEG image. I am using following code in console.

```
require 'rmagick'

i = Magick::Image.read("test.jpg")[0]

puts i.interlace # => NoInterlace
i.write("test2.jpg") { self.interlace = Magick::PlaneInterlace }

puts i.interlace # => PlaneInterlace
```

My problem is when I upload this local instance of image to AWS using this pice of code

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store("test2.jpg", thumb.to_blob, AWS_BUCKET, :content_type => 'image/png', :access => :public_read)
```

And when I am trying to open this image in browser its not getting converted in progressive JPEG image.

Please help me how I can work with it.

Comment: Would it be possible that you need to close the file, before uploading it? Addtionally, I would use 2 filenames, the source, and the converted filename, to make sure the right file is selected. It is also easier for tracking a workflow, when you suddenly would need another step before interlacing.

Comment: I don't know AWS, but are you sure you want `:content_type => 'image/png'` as a param to the store method? Could this get reflected back to the browser when downloading, thus it would ignore possibility that it is receiving a progressing jpeg (and then, browsers being as they are, realises at the end it doesn't have a png and fix itself)?